# I get an error when 'await' is in front of client.send_message

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I'm using discord.py version 0.16.8. Also my client is: `client = discord.Client()`.

When tying to write `await client.send_message(All the usual code is in here)` I get an error on await that says:
"Class 'Message' does not define '**await**', so the 'await' operator cannot be used on its instances".

When I try to run my Bot in Discord and try one of my commands it doesn't work, and no message pops up. This is my code for the command:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == '..roll':
    await client.send_message(message.channel, str(randint(1, 6)))
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot indent in `if` statement

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == '..roll':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, str(randint(1, 6)))
```